# MAMP Pro MySQL Won't Start

Tags: mysql, mamp

I have tried everything from every forum, still no love. Deleted temp files, even a totally clean re-install.

Even created a new user on my Mac.... same issue.

Here's the MySQL log file:

2018-12-15T09:47:47.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2018-12-15T09:47:47.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57
2018-12-15T09:47:48.230415Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2018-12-15T09:47:48.232313Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.23) starting as process 3631 ...
2018-12-15T09:47:48.249599Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2018-12-15T09:47:48.266106Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-12-15T09:47:48.266181Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-12-15T09:47:48.266203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-12-15T09:47:48.266221Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-12-15T09:47:48.266277Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2018-12-15T09:47:48.269905Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-12-15T09:47:48.273776Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-12-15T09:47:48.279178Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-12-15T09:47:48.301106Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-12-15T09:47:48.335445Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-12-15T09:47:48.339844Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 72309002 and the end 72308736.
2018-12-15T09:47:48.339913Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-12-15T09:47:48.642547Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-12-15T09:47:48.642595Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-12-15T09:47:48.642616Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-12-15T09:47:48.642631Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-12-15T09:47:48.643113Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-12-15T09:47:48.644288Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-12-15T09:47:48.645917Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2018-12-15T09:47:48.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
2018-12-15T09:58:04.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2018-12-15T09:58:04.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57
2018-12-15T09:58:05.259005Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2018-12-15T09:58:05.261261Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.23) starting as process 4301 ...
2018-12-15T09:58:05.280531Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2018-12-15T09:58:05.298055Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-12-15T09:58:05.298134Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-12-15T09:58:05.298163Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-12-15T09:58:05.298189Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-12-15T09:58:05.298249Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2018-12-15T09:58:05.301851Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-12-15T09:58:05.306424Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-12-15T09:58:05.310212Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-12-15T09:58:05.334016Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-12-15T09:58:05.390575Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-12-15T09:58:05.395800Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Ignoring the redo log due to missing MLOG_CHECKPOINT between the checkpoint 72309002 and the end 72308736.
2018-12-15T09:58:05.395949Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-12-15T09:58:05.706951Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-12-15T09:58:05.707019Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-12-15T09:58:05.707057Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-12-15T09:58:05.707106Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-12-15T09:58:05.707807Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-12-15T09:58:05.709523Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2018-12-15T09:58:05.711283Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2018-12-15T09:58:05.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended

Comment: What version of mamp and what version of mac OS are you using?

Comment: Latest MAMP and High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Also this occurred when I lost power to my laptop and after restarting the Mysql would not start... thanks

Comment: I never had this issue, I'm on MAMP 3.5 (but I've decided to not update to the latest versions), I can suggest you to deeply clear your system using a tool like AppCleaner. Backup you projects inside the `htdocs` and then by using the suggested app remove MAMP. Then re-install it (try with a different version). Probably there are some MAMP files that are corrupted.

Comment: Thanks, did all these steps as well.... and even on a new user, blank account with a clean install as noted above....

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo killall -9 mysqld
```

Run the code in terminal and restart MAMP server.